# Timeout during scaffolding dbcontext for net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, scaffolding

i am trying to scaffold my DB-Context for my Net Core Application.

I use the following command, because "Scaffold-DbContext" is not known. I am sure i allready did it with this command on another computer.

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Connection String" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models_Server --verbose

What is the design-time services and how can i get it?

verbose output:

```
...
Finding design-time services for provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'... 
Using design-time services from provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'.                
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'ib.api_core'. 
No referenced design-time services were found. 
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'ib.api_core'...      
No design-time services were found.
```

ERROR:

```
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out. 
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 703                                                                         
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 555
cts\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 414                                                                                                                                                
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\ConnectorPool.cs:line 246                                                                                                                                                                                           
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 301                                           
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---                                                                                                                     
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 153                                                                                               
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection dbConnection, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas) in C:\projects\npgsql-entityframeworkcore-postgresql\src\EFCore.PG\Scaffolding\Internal\NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.cs:line 102                                                                                      
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas) in C:\projects\npgsql-entityframeworkcore-postgresql\src\EFCore.PG\Scaffolding\Internal\NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.cs:line 86                                                                                         
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String namespace, String language, String contextDir, String contextName, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)                                                             
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)                                                              
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)                                                      
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()                                                                                  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()                                                                                
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)                                                                                             
The operation has timed out.
```

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <UserSecretsId>5a596668-4322-425e-a721-a9f91d12308c</UserSecretsId>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\**" />
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Communication\**" />
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Extensions\**" />
    <Content Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\**" />
    <Content Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Communication\**" />
    <Content Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Extensions\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Communication\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Extensions\**" />
    <None Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\**" />
    <None Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Communication\**" />
    <None Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Extensions\**" />
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\IbServerConnector.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\IbItemCreator.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\lib\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.9.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AutoMapper">
      <HintPath>Controllers\ServerConnector\lib\AutoMapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="IB.Common.ClassLibrary">
      <HintPath>Controllers\ServerConnector\bin\IB.Common.ClassLibrary.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="IB.Common.Components">
      <HintPath>Controllers\ServerConnector\bin\IB.Common.Components.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="IB.Common.Extensions">
      <HintPath>Controllers\ServerConnector\bin\IB.Common.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="IB.Communication.Client">
      <HintPath>Controllers\ServerConnector\bin\IB.Communication.Client.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="IB.Communication.Common">
      <HintPath>Controllers\ServerConnector\bin\IB.Communication.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="IB.Communication.Interfaces">
      <HintPath>Controllers\ServerConnector\bin\IB.Communication.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration">
      <HintPath>Libraries\System.configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\ClassLibrary\app.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\GuiUtil\app.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\HbnManager\app.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Communication\ClientApp\App.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Communication\Client\packages.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Communication\ServerApp\App.config" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\Components\obj\IB.Common.Components.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Controllers\ServerConnector\Common\Components\obj\project.assets.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Got the same issue, did you manage to solve it? I am also using Postgresql and the same provider, but version 3.1.2

Comment: @Duckslayer i chaned my command to this: `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Connection String" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o {output folder}`